# RSA Encryption issue between C# and Java using Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, java, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm facing a couple of issues with a Java app and another in C#. Here is the thing. There's a server application that receives request through HTTP, process it and sends
back the response. This server is writting in Java with Bouncy Castle and we use PKI to encrypt sensitive data in the request. We have many operations that the server recognizes
and one of the them is used to generate the the public and private keys used to exchange with the clients. Each client has a unique ID, so when this operation named
GetEncryptionKey is executed, it generates the private key and save it locally in the server and generates the public key which is sent back in PEM format, like this:

```
encryptionKey=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAon1WDHdarN7yq0UOevzW
5PiFsSC8bEkTUOZ6X3RIth+RCU42pUj/Z8fp9T8rbWp8CqbhlFDxU4c+YucpGljC
7A10nkrPoBT0lpHEuXJiSgx+9qqsyo9q6GddhOpdMa+Z6VCfI+JCM3kdJNMH3r+o
i+WLPHLB8lxnfT2CHyZVQGhkzrH9fk1XhdenXxjtPGpwYBOsUZUwRt8EeW6JUwSI
mKXiXag0IViEcyAa2BvProkxklbQB3BczLHdXjIDwnE6u1aMA7pYPSkBtY6tuQ0F
5sNWXHsaKWON33MnbhlM7sieYDi9L4dWksala/m/mdIeHIXzX4ZCYdOhayWWKZ1N
HwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This is working ok. The code used to generate the key is the following one:

```
private void getEncryptedKey()  throws GWTranException {

    PEMWriter pemWriter;

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyPair keyPair = null;

    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = null;

    try {
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    try {

        pemWriter = new PEMWriter(new PrintWriter(writer));
        pemWriter.writeObject(keyPair.getPublic());
        pemWriter.flush();
        String pem = writer.toString();

        savePrivateKey(keyPair, pem);           // save the private key locally

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I have a client written in C# that connects to the server, retrieves the Public Key sent in the response and use it to encrypt a string that will travel encrypted.
This is the .NET code (very simple, as I'm just testing the functionality):

```
private string EncryptDataWithRSA(string data) {

    string cryptedData = string.Empty;

    RsaKeyParameters rsaParams;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(txtKey.Text)) {
        rsaParams = (RsaKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
        reader.Close();
    }

    IAsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new RsaEngine();
    eng = new OaepEncoding(eng);
    eng.Init(true, rsaParams);

    var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    var cryptedDataBytes = eng.ProcessBlock(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
    cryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(cryptedDataBytes);

    return cryptedData;
}
```

Everything looks nice but the problem is that when the server (Java app) tries to decrypt the data I get an exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: data hash wrong
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at com.verifone.gateway.security.RSAEncryptUtil.decrypt(RSAEncryptUtil.java:127)
    at com.verifone.gateway.security.RSAEncryptUtil.decrypt(RSAEncryptUtil.java:152)
    at com.verifone.gateway.preonline.PreOnlineJob.decryptData(PreOnlineJob.java:1661)
    at com.verifone.gateway.preonline.PreOnlineJob.extractCardData(PreOnlineJob.java:989)
    at com.verifone.gateway.preonline.PreOnlineJob.run(PreOnlineJob.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is working fine with another client writting in iOS but I don't have access to the source code. I'm writting a simulator in .NET but I'm not being able to
get the information decrypted correctly. On the server side this is part of the code used to decrypt the data:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] text, PrivateKey key) throws Exception
{
    byte[] dectyptedText = null;
    try {
        // decrypt the text using the private key
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //_log.error(e, e);
        throw e;
    }

    return dectyptedText;
}
```

I'm out of ideas, I've tried everything. Do you see something I don't?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: remove the text in the starting 'encryptionKey=' this could be issue.

Comment: Also, if you edit the key by any chance anywhere in the code, do not do it. even deleting an emptyline is not allwed

Comment: No, this part is not used to get the key. RsaKeyParameters object is created correctly. I'm not changing anything on the key. Thanks anyway Zeus

Comment: I see that you are converting to base64 on the client, is is decoded to byte[] from base 64?

Comment: Good oberservation. Anyway, yes, it's converting it from Base64 with something like: BASE64Decoder b64 = new BASE64Decoder(); return b64.decodeBuffer(text);

Comment: I think the problem might be how the data is padded in the client. I'm using OaepEncoding class, but I don't know if the mode is correct. In java, the cipher is created as "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding", but I'm not sure how to check if it's using ECB or not.

Comment: I would compare the hex of the client value of encryption and the hex after it is decoded from the base64 on the server, if they are equal, then next thing would be,change the padding as mentioned here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher looks like you are not using anhy padding on the client use RSA/None/NoPadding . since you are doing a 2048 encryption, there is a way on the java side to set this before you call doFinal, i dont recall.

Comment: to know the padding info, privatekey/publickey may have this info, if you print the privateKey.toString() it might show on java.

Comment: On the client I'm using RSA/???/OAEPPadding. The questions marks is because I'm not sure what mode I'm using. Maybe the Bouncy Castle version for .NET doesn't support ECB Cipher mode?

Comment: ECB mode is supported, yes, and you are effectively using it here. Alternative C# code to look more like the Java would be: IBufferedCipher c = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding"); c.Init(true, publicKey); byte[] output = c.DoFinal(dataBytes);

Comment: I'm a bit biased, but I think it very unlikely there's a problem in the actual RSA/OAEP implementation in BC. The two things you should double- and triple-check are that the exact same bytes are input to the cipher at both ends (I suggest printing out in hex a digest of dataBytes/test, right before the ProcessBlock/doFinal calls), and that the correct PrivateKey is loaded when decrypting. Preferably create a standalone program of the relevant server code to remove any extraneous factors.